# Unsigned and Signed Integers

Tags: c++, integer-promotion

If I have a compiler that uses a 2 byte `short` and a 4 byte `int`, why are the last two lines of output different for my code?

I get that `x + y` overflows the `short` type. But are the last two lines different because math has at least int precision, you can print out the large value or because `z` is automatically converted to an `unsigned int` to print it?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main() {
    unsigned short x = 65'535;
    unsigned short y = 1;
    unsigned short z = x + y;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
    cout << z << endl;
    cout << x + y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Because of arithmetic promotions.

Comment: Curious, does this even compile? `unsigned short x = 65'535;`

Comment: @KerrekSB so x + y overflows the short type. But because math has at least int precision, you can print out the large value?

Comment: @nakiya it should in c++ 14. They added the ' as a sort of comma for large numbers. Not a problem in compile time

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same<int, decltype(x + y)>::value, "int");`

Comment: @nakiya yes, you can put `'` anywhere inside an integer literal and the compiler ignores it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for `cout << x + y`, you're printing out an `int` directly; For [arithmetic operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions), before computation their operands will be [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)ed, so the result of `x + y` will be an `int`.

> If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes integral promotion.

On the other hand, `z` is `unsigned short`; when the result of `x + y` (i.e. an `int`) is assigned to `z` implicit conversion is performed (and overflow happens).

Comment: Oh okay. So z is automatically converted to an unsigned int to print it?

Comment: @SethKillian Yes. The result of `x + y` (i.e. an `int`) is implicitly converted to `unsigned short` when assigned to `z`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @songyuanyao : Then why is it that at `z = x + y` where `z` is `unsigned short`, the compiler is silent? Shouldn't it warn that `z` cannot hold an int?

Comment: @nakiya Because the standard allows such kind of [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) (more precisely, integral conversions). From C++11, you can use list initlization form, like `unsigned short z { x + y };`, which doesn't allow narrow conversions. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qlqcTWu7Iu6gFeyn)

Comment: Since `z` is unsigned , assigning to it cannot overflow (using the Standard's terminology). An out of range assignment will be adjusted modulo `USHRT_MAX+1`.